# Getting transfer/swap fee for ethereum/bsc tokens

Tags: python, blockchain

How is it possible to get transfer/swap buy and swap sell fees for every token on erc20 chain, as well as on bep20 chain when swapping on uniswap/pancakeswap?

I know that these data are on the contract code that I can find on the bscscan or etherscan but the code is always different for each token and I need to find a solution that allows me to get all these data for each and every token. I would be so grateful for anyone that could offer anything!

Comment: There is a website for checking those fees - https://bscheck.eu. It takes it from somewhere. Since it doesn't have any API or anything - I need to find out where it takes it from.